# How to handle Swiper 11 Web component events in Angular 17 SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, swiper.js, angular17, angular-ssr

I have this code working perfectly fine but I want to start using Swiper Webcomponent. How do I migrate this code to Swiper Webcomponent, specially, how to handle the events,

Here, I have slideChangeTransitionStart, slideChangeTransitionEnd event.
On slideChangeTransitionEnd event, I need to call a method called setupImageZoom

HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-container swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="swiper-zoom-container"><img style="width: 100%;" [src]="slide.image"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-container thumbs-swiper thumbs-hover">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container"><img style="width: 100%;" [src]="slide.image"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
slides = [
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-1.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-2.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-3.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-4.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-5.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-6.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-7.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-8.jpg'},
    {image: '../../../../../assets/images/swiper-nature/nature-10.jpg'}
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const thumbsSwiper = new Swiper(".thumbs-swiper", {
      loop: false,
      direction: 'vertical',
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 6,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
      centeredSlides: true,
      centeredSlidesBounds: true,
      watchOverflow: true,
      watchSlidesVisibility: true,
    });
    const mainSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
      direction: 'horizontal',
      loop: false,
      speed: 400,
      spaceBetween: 100,
      mousewheel: {
        invert: true,
      },
      grabCursor: true,
      effect: 'creative',
      creativeEffect: {
        prev: {
          translate: [0, 0, -400],
        },
        next: {
          translate: ['100%', 0, 0],
        },
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination'
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      zoom: {
        maxRatio: 10,
      },
      thumbs: {
        swiper: thumbsSwiper
      } 
    });
    mainSwiper.on("slideChangeTransitionStart",  () => {
      console.log('slideChangeTransitionStart');
      thumbsSwiper.slideTo(mainSwiper.activeIndex);
    });
    mainSwiper.on("slideChangeTransitionEnd", () => {
      console.log('mainSwiper slideChangeTransitionEnd');
      thumbsSwiper.slideTo(mainSwiper.activeIndex);
      this.setupImageZoom();
    });

    thumbsSwiper.on("slideChangeTransitionEnd", () => {
      console.log('thumbsSwiper slideChangeTransitionEnd');
      mainSwiper.slideTo(thumbsSwiper.activeIndex);
    });

  this.setupImageZoom();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation on [`Swiper Elements`](https://swiperjs.com/element#events), we can just add the prefix `swiper` to the events, so

> All Swiper events are available as native DOM events but with lowercase names and swiper prefix (configurable via events-prefix parameter). **E.g. slideChange becomes swiperslidechange.**

html

```
<swiper-container
  slides-per-view="1"
  speed="500"
  loop="true"
  navigation="true"
  pagination="true"
  #swiper
  scrollbar="true"
  (swiperslidechangetransitionend)="setupImageZoom()"
>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper',
  standalone: true,
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  templateUrl: './swiper.component.html',
})
export class SwiperComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {}

  setupImageZoom() {
    alert('setting up zoom!');
  }
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jthnez?file=src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.html,src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Naren,
This doesn't work out. If you check this in console.log, for every slide change the method is triggered so many times. Specially, I need to trigger on slideChangeTransitionEnd

Comment: Yes, this event is working fine now. Thanks.